# Graphic Libraries for 2D (No XNA please)

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d

Since Microsoft are dropping XNA (and yes, I know that one can still use it quite successfully, but the fact it's not being developed after only a short period of existence speaks volumes).
What are the best C# graphic libraries for simple 2D development (akin to Allegro, SFML, SDL and the likes)? By the best I mean those under active development, with an active community, and hopefully with some decent tutorials.

I tried searching for an answer but, one way or another, it's XNA that always comes up (maybe for a reason...)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered Monogame? is the XNA api and it's under heavy development check github.com/mono/monogame

Comment: This question is both useful and constructive. It needs to be reopened.

Comment: @ThunderGr It's explicitly asking for off-site resources. It needs to be closed.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It is closed as non-constructive. Asking for information about programming resources is not forbidden either. MS dropping XNA has been a real problem for everyone trying to program games in windows. So, I still think it needs to be reopened.

Comment: Absolutely confused as to why this is closed. The question is certainly open to answers "supported by facts, references, or expertise," and is not "asking for off-site resources" (not even implicitly—asking which libraries where support exists is not the same as asking for support for those libraries). This was the second result that came up in my search and we have for some reason elected not to be a source of useful, relevant information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) or [TaoFramework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/).

There are a lot of tutorials. One of them can be found [here](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/using-opengl-in-c-taoframework/).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! Somehow missed it on Google in favor of SDL wrappers and such.

Comment: OpenTK is far from being actively developed, their last release was >3 years ago...

Comment: OpenTK is still active and part of it is used in MonoDevelop. Relatively, TaoFramework is even less active. 3 years..., is not so outdated, and the quality of OpenTK, I think, is worthy the attention.

Comment: These are frameworks, not libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks I like:

- for openGL - [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/)
- for DirectX - [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)

For the libraries you have listed there is a wrapper for SDL [SDL.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-sdl/)

Re-adding content that was removed in a review (WHY? The answer is not XNA, but Open Source implementation of XNA)

Also if you are familiar with XNA you can use [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/) - implementation of XNA under active development. Playstation Mobile and Raspberry PI support is under development.